# Update a custom store object

Tags: typescript, svelte

I have a store

```
export const tenantStore = writable({
    name: undefined,
    vatObligation: undefined,
    simplifiedAccounting: undefined
  })
```

and want to read and change the value of an attribute of the store when someone clicks a checkbox, like here:

```
<script>
    import { tenantStore } from '../../store/stores.js'
    import { updateTenant } from '../../api/api.ts'

    let vatObligation = Boolean($tenantStore.vatObligation)
    let simplifiedAccounting = Boolean($tenantStore.simplifiedAccounting)

    $: {
        console.log("vatObligation: " + $tenantStore.vatObligation)
        console.log("simplifiedAccounting: " + $tenantStore.simplifiedAccounting)
        console.log(vatObligation)
    }
</script>

<div class="headline">
  Einstellungen zur Organisation
</div>
<div class="line">
  <label class="description" for="vatObligation">Ust-pflichtig</label>
  <input class="input" type="checkbox" bind:checked={vatObligation}/>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <label class="description" for="simplifiedAccounting">EüR-berechtigt</label>
  <input class="input" type="checkbox" bind:checked={simplifiedAccounting}/>
</div>
```

When I toggle the checkboxes the given code logs

```
vatObligation: true
simplifiedAccounting: true
true
vatObligation: true
simplifiedAccounting: true
false
```

As you can see, the attributes of the store are not updated. I'd like to directly wire it to the checkbox but I haven't managed to do so. When I try I run into

> can't assign to property on true: not an object svelte

What would be a good way to update the store value. The goal is to catch an update and POST the whole config. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of ways you can update a store dynamically from an input, including directly or indirectly via a function.

Given a simple writeable store...

stores.js:

```js
import {writable} from "svelte/store";

export const writableStore = writable({
    a: true,
    b: true
});
```

... here's two examples of updating the values, directly (a) or indirectly (b):

App.svelte:

```svelte
<script>
    import {writableStore} from "./stores.js";
    
    let b = $writableStore.b;
    
    // This function could be on a "custom" store.
    function updateB( value ) {
        // Validate value in context of other values?
        // Send to API.
        // Result good ... update store.
        $writableStore.b = value;
        
        return $writableStore.b;
    }
    
    $: bCurrent = updateB( b );
    </script>

<h2>A: {$writableStore.a}</h2>
<label for="a">Toggle A</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="a" bind:checked={$writableStore.a} />

<h2>B: {bCurrent}</h2>
<label for="b">Toggle B</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="b" bind:checked={b} />
```

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/fb09138522d84e7e9fbb642193e8258c?version=3.45.0

The example for `b` waits to update the store, which may not be what you want.

If you can send to API via a "Save" button, then the example for `a` may be all you need, calling a function via the button to send the store data to the API etc.

These are just super simple examples, I tend to use functions on custom stores for saving to the API etc and using the store's `update()` function to sync results.

Comment: I was pretty sure I tried `bind:checked={$writableStore.a}` but this is working so thank you a lot!